# How to stop Hubspot forms adding additional scroller on Google sites

Tags: javascript, forms, embed, google-sites, hubspot

I've noticed `the Hubspot form` embedded on my Google sites is adding an additional scroller. When viewed on a `mobile device browser`, this is really confusing for an unfamiliar viewer. It's unclear where the user should hold their finger to scroll down the page.

> Is there a way to have the embedded form be part of the page and
> scroll all at once, not two scrollers?

This is the code from Hubspot forms:

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/shell.js"></script>
<script>
  hbspt.forms.create({
    region: "na1",
    portalId: "9155464",
    formId: "f6a32df3-0cdc-4c91-b71f-19fd4d623f57"
});
</script>
```

This is the link to the page: https://www.oneperis.com/venue-partners (view on mobile device)